# IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level 122324

Tags: python-3.x

Well i dont got any blank spaces on my code but still the messages shows up
IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level
Does anybody knows whats going on? The error is on line 7

I already tried to shift+tb it to see if there were any blank spaces

[image]

IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level

Comment: Your problem is that the second else statement is indented by 2 extra spaces, easy mistake, I know :)